# Is there any identity for A×(nabla×B)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried to find one using Einstein notations but I am stuck on the following step:
Aj di Bj - An dj Bi
The right term is (A.nabla)B but what does the left term represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's just do it: $$\begin{align} A\times (\nabla\times B) &= \epsilon^i_{~jk}A^j(\nabla \times B)^k e_i \\ &= \epsilon^i_{~jk}A^j \epsilon^{kr}_{~~~s} \partial_rB^s e_i \\ &= \epsilon^i_{~jk}\epsilon^{kr}_{~~ s~}A^j\partial_rB^s e_i \\ &= \epsilon_{k\phantom{i}j}^{\phantom{k}i}\epsilon^{kr}_{~~ s~}A^j\partial_rB^s e_i \\ &= (\delta^{ir}\delta_{js} - \delta^i_s\delta^r_j)A^j\partial_rB^se_i \\ &= \delta^{ir}\delta_{js}A^j\partial_rB^se_i - \delta^i_s\delta^r_jA^j\partial_rB^se_i \\ &= \delta_{js}A^j\partial_iB^se_i - A^j\partial_jB^ie_i \\ &= (\nabla B)A - (A\cdot \nabla)B,\end{align}$$where $(\nabla B)A$ is the $3\times 3$ matrix $\nabla B$ formed by the gradients of the components of $B$ applied to the $3\times 1$ column vector $A$ -- which gives a $3\times 1$ column vector $(\nabla B)A$, which can be operated together with $(A\cdot \nabla)B$.

Comment: OK so I found this identity in my fluid mechanics text as V×(∇×V)= ∇(V^2/2) - (V.∇)V,  where V is the velocity vector field. As per your answer, if I were to put V in place of A and B we get (∇V)V for (∇B)A. So (∇V)V =  ∇(V^2/2)? So correct me if I am wrong. (∇V) is a 3×3 tensor and V is a 3×1 matrix which will yield ∇(V^2/2) which a 3×1 matrix?

Comment: I think so, because if $A=B$ then $$\delta_{js}A^j\partial_iA^s =\frac{1}{2}\partial_i(A\cdot A).$$